# Can we deploy OpenStack directly on bare metal?

Tags: openstack

I am learning about OpenStack deployment. It's bit confusing for me to understand what are the prerequisite for OpenStack deployment.

Can I deploy OpenStack directly on the native OS like Docker (e.g using Linux LXC ) ?

Or if not then what type of Hypervisors does it runs on (type 1 and/or type2) ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I deploy OpenStack directly on the native OS like Docker (e.g using Linux LXC ) ?

That is the primary use case for OpenStack.  It is effectively a resource scheduler for infrastructure resources (storage, networking, compute), and in production environments generally runs on physical hardware and then allocates on-demand virtual machines via the various APIs.

> Or if not then what type of Hypervisors does it runs on (type 1 and/or type2) ?

For development and testing purposes, you can run OpenStack in any kind of hypervisor (or even in Docker or LXC containers).  In terms of what hypervisors it *supports* (not "runs on" but "can schedule resources  on), see https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/HypervisorSupportMatrix.